# How To Play Video in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Question is simple but I'm near the solution..

In my windows store project, I need to play video in my video gallery page. I get the url from my web api. I get the "video_id" from selection_changed event, but could not put it into my media element.. My link is ready, I just need to put it in a media element..

this is my xaml side ;

```
<Grid x:Name="VideoGaleriFlipGrid" 
              Grid.Column="1" 
              Grid.Row="1">
            <MediaElement x:Name="MyMediaPlayer"
                          AutoPlay="False"/>
</Grid>
```

and my cs codes;

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            if (e.Parameter == null) return;
            var clickedItem = e.Parameter.ToString();
            var index = int.Parse(clickedItem);
            var url = "http://myapi.mywebsite.com.tr/Video?videoID=" + index;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var videodata = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                _videos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoApi.RootObject>(videodata);
                //MyMediaPlayer.Source = _videos.Video[1].videourl3;
                //MyMediaPlayer.DataContext = _videos.Video[1].videourl3;
            }
        }
```

Commented lines doesn't work you know..
And I get the right videodata and right videourl3 when check with breakpoint..

I googled but couldn't find a situation like mine.
I need help about this..
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`MyMediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(_videos.Video[1].videourl3)`;

Comment: thanks for the answer but, it show just first frame of video. My video is .mp4 format.. Is it about that ?

Comment: You have set auto play to false, so it will not play. You need to use `MyMediaPlayer.Play()` in `MyMediaPlayer`'s `Loaded` event.

Comment: Oh, my bad.. Thanks, it works. By the way, how can I add play and pause buttons on it ? Is there any controls for it ?

Comment: No, you need to do manually. Check out [XAML media playback sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-media-playback-sample-6d76261b)

Comment: The link for the sample is changed.Here it is [http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Media-Playback-003619be/view/Discussions]

Comment: @Kuthay, in 8.1 they added transport controls to the MediaElement. You would need to set AreTransportControlsEnabled to true, but it will only work for 8.1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but mainly, people have windows 8.. So I need to solve in that way.. I need help about this..